# Mini index for subsection

Tags: indexing, subdividing

There is the following code:

```
\subsection{some subsection}
Some \mindex[mean=aaa]{sentence} with some \mindex[mean=bbb]{unknown} words.
\listminiindexfromsubsection
```

The expected output:

> Some subsection
>
> Some sentence with some unknown words.
>
> Mini index: sentence - aaa unknown - bbb

I would like to create something like a mini index, which can create a small dictionary. All words from specific subsection which are arguments of `\mindex[mean=something]{word}` should be collected and when the command `\listminiindexfromsubsection` is written, then the output should contain all of these words with their meaning.

What is the method to collect specific words from a subsection and then printing them out?

Comment: Where is the `\mindex` command defined?

Comment: it's not yet defined, it's just example how it could be defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\def\mindexlist{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mindex}[2]{\g@addto@macro\mindexlist{\textbf{#1} --- #2\par}#2}
\newcommand{\printmindex}{\begin{flushleft}\mindexlist\end{flushleft}
  \gdef\mindexlist{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{First}
Some \mindex{sentence}{aaa} with some \mindex{unknown}{bbb} words.

\printmindex

\section{Second}
Some \mindex{sentence}{ccc} with some \mindex{unknown}{ddd} words.

\printmindex
\end{document}
```

Each `\printmindex` command resets the list.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps not as simple as you expected, but also not much difficult. You can use the [glossaries](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) package and create one glossary for each subsection:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nonumberlist,savewrites,xindy,nomain]{glossaries}

 % Define new glossaries
\newglossary[sco]{seco}{oin}{ofi}{Short Index}
\newglossary[sct]{sect}{tin}{tfi}{Short Index}

\makeglossaries

% declare the entries
\newglossaryentry{seco:unk}{type=seco, name={unknown}, description={Not known}}

\newglossaryentry{seco:sen}{type=seco,name={sentence},description={Some description}}

\newglossaryentry{sect:rin}{type=sect,name={ring},description={Not known}}

\newglossaryentry{sect:gro}{type=sect,name={group},description={Simple structure}}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}

\subsection{First subsection}
This is a \gls{seco:sen} with some \gls{seco:unk} words.
\printglossary[type=seco]

\subsection{Second subsection}
A \gls{sect:rin} is an algebraic structure whose definition is not known; A \gls{sect:gro} is a simple algebraic structure.
\printglossary[type=sect]

\end{document}
```

The example (let's call the above document `test.tex`) can be compiled using:

```
(pdf)latex test
makeglossaries test
(pdf)latex test
(pdf)latex test
```

The result:

[image]